# is it possible to create a 2D viewpager in android composed of activities?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I basically need 5 main things in my app:

- separate screen for the camera,
- screen for users profile,
- screen for the friend list,
- screen which shows interesting places around the users location
- an option screen.

I would like to have 4 of them horizontally orientated and the user should be able to navigate through these screens by swiping. And the fifth screen, the options screen suppose to be "above" of the screen row. 
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGLJ5.jpg).

And the user should be able to access this fifth screen from any other screen by swiping up. 
So I researched a lot and I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

Should I use activities for such a screen Order cause every Screen has a total different navigating menu and they have actually nothing common, so I thought there is no need for a fragment, not to mention if it is even possible to realize it with fragments.

I don't know if it is possible to create this 2 dimensional view pager with activities cause I think it's not easy to create a proper swipe between two activities, not to mention for a 2D view pager. 
So is it possible to realize such a thing with activities?

If not, am I suppose to use fragments and if so, what I'm gonna do with the fifth screen. I know that every fragment need a parent activity so how to manage the fifth screen when using a view pager for the four horizontal screen's ? Or can I include vertical swipes in a viewpager as well?

I got stuck with these several questions for more than a week already. I just don't wanna try it and then realize, I chose the wrong way to do it. 
Cause I'm at the very beginning and so it's for me a lot of effort to even figure out how to start with one of these possibilities.

I would be very thankful if one of u could give me some advices for where and how to start.

And sorry for the bad english.

Comment: for now I'm using a viewpager with 4 fragments attached to one main activity but I don't know how to create the vertical swipe to the fifth screen with  proper swipe animation. And I would like to use then fragments inside the option screen to display the options more detailed but I've read it is not possible to use fragments inside fragments so that's the reason I struggle with this solution.

Comment: you need to use fragments please check below link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/VerticalViewPager.java

Comment: @surya thanks for the fast response, I try to make out

Comment: @surya how to I include this into my code? I got already a normal viewpager, how do I use them both together?

Comment: you got the vertical viewpager working ??if so you need both so you initiliase the proper viewpager based on touch events.